# How to disable copy,paste options in UITextView and enable it again iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uimenucontroller, disabled-control

Am working in UITextView based iPhone app. In one of my screen i having 3 UITextView when the user tap on the screen am showing UIMenuController with custom MenuItems. `In this scenario UITextView is in Active means UITextView is becomResponder. So when i show UIMenuItem taping the screen UITextView UIMenuController showing with "Paste" option.`

I want to disable UIMenuController item from UITextView when the user touches the screen. `Could you please anyone tell me how to disable UITextView with showing keypad and disable UIMenuController.?` Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can Code like this:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

other wise you can write:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

To make your textfiled noneditable. Hope it works for you.